# How to implement parent child relationship checkbox in SWT?

Tags: java, checkbox, swt

I am new to SWT, my requirement is I need to add two checkboxes in a dialog. I want, if I select first checkbox second should also be selected. 
But if I am disabling second checkbox , first one is still selected. I am not allowed to select second checkbox, second checkbox is only selected when first checkbox is selected. I believe its a parent child relationship and CheckboxTreeViewer must be used(still not sure). Can anyone please send across code snippet for the requirement?

Comment: What you're asking is very broad. What have you tried so far? Can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Two ordinary SWT.CHECK Buttons should be OK with selection listeners that enforce the conditions. I don't think CheckboxTreeViewer would really help.

Answer (score 2):

**Check out below code:**

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.*;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.*;

public class CheckBoxExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Display display = new Display();
        Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, true));

        Button parentButton = new Button(shell, SWT.CHECK);
        parentButton.setText("Parent");
        Button childButton = new Button(shell, SWT.CHECK);
        childButton.setText("Child");
        childButton.setEnabled(false);

        parentButton.addListener(SWT.Selection, event -> {
            if (!parentButton.getSelection()) {
                childButton.setEnabled(false);
                childButton.setSelection(false);
                return;
            }
            childButton.setEnabled(true);
        });

        shell.pack();
        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
        display.dispose();
    }
}
```

**Output for above code**

[image: Step1]
[image: Step2]
[image: Step3]
[image: Step4]
[image: Step5]

Comment: Hi Shashwat, commenting pretty late but have implemented your suggested code. 
It is working fine but I am facing one problem with it.As per you code, once the dialog loads for the first time , childButton is showing enabled. 
It is showing disable when I am selecting parentButton and then again unchecking parentButton.
But I want to show childButton  to show grayed out once the dialog loads for the very first time. Could you please suggect the workaround?

Comment: You can checkout `setGrayed()` method if its suites your use case

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I tried two things 1) making parentButton as final, it is indeed showing me childButton by default as inactive. I select parentButton and childButton is also selected (As desired) . But now I am not able to uncheck childButton. Although my requirement is I can check/uncheck childButton (only if parentButton is checked) . 2) As you suggested I did setGrayed(true) in if (!parentButton.getSelection()) {
             childButton.setGrayed(true);childButton.setSelection(false);return  } . and childButton is now blocked.No actions can be performed. Please suggest

Comment: I am not able to understand what is your requirement, So please put you working code in question. As you said "Although my requirement is I can check/uncheck childButton (only if parentButton is checked)" this means child button should be disabled not grayed